# Save open applications

Tags: gnome-shell

When I close my Gnome-shell with some open applications, I would like to restore them in the same state to the next start : how can I do that (I'm on Ubuntu Gnome-shell 14.04.02 LTS) ?

If I use gnome-session-properties, I have only applications and nowhere to select "Automatically remember running applications when logging out".

Thanks

Comment: Hi again, So, with gconf-editor, I changed org/gnome/gnome-session/auto_save_session to put on true and nothing changed (and again, I don't have checkbox in gnome-session-properties for "Automatically remember running applications when logging out"). I don't know what to do more.Thanks